# Django: context of modified query list

Tags: django, django-views

I have a database with blog style documents, i.e., author's name, publication date, body text, etc.

I have built a django framework to output entries from the database as a result of a search term. That part is ok. The problem is that I want to show sections of the body text with the matched search terms highlighted (equivalent to a google search result). This means that I can't create a template tag with the body_text attribute only, because that text is not highlighted. I already did a function that receives as input the query and the body text and outputs the same text with the found search terms in bold. 
My problem now is how do I pass this result to the html template?

Using the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/) from Django documentation suppose you have the following views.py:

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

and the correspondent template:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Now suppose you have the function in views.py:

```
def signal_tokens(text,query_q):
    ...
    return new_text
```

What should be the best way to replace the `{{ question.question_text }` with the output from `signal_tokens`? My solution was to replicate the context variable with a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary is a copy of each entry, except for the `'question_text'` key, where I used `signal_tokens` result:

```
def index(request):
    query_q = 'test'
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    new_context = []
    for entry in latest_question_list:
        temp_d = {}
        temp_d['id'] =  entry.id
        temp_d['question_text'] = signal_tokens(entry.question_text,query_q)
        new_context.append(temp_d)
    context = {'latest_question_list': new_context}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

But the problem is that I need to copy all entries. Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an ideal use case for a [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters). Move your highlight code to a file in the templatetags directory, register it as a filter, then you can call it from the template:

```
{{ question.question_text|highlight:query_q }}
```

Obviously you will need to pass `query_q` to the template context as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!